# Talend Administartion Centre in container

Tags: talend

How can we run Talend Admin Center(TAC) in a container so that we do not have to upload the license everytime?

Appreciate inputs.

Thanks!

Comment: Normally you just have to put the licence once , from the TAC ('licence' menu). A new licence must be set only if the current one is expiring.  What is exactly happening ?

Comment: The idea is what happens when I try to containerize TAC and run it over DC/OS. I can configure once the licence, but when for some reason a new container is spined up, how can I automate license upload process?